# How to distribute my IOS app without app store 2022?

Tags: ios

i would like to use my app from my server. I tried to use In-House Distribution but Apple didn't approved it for few employees. I have been using TestFlight but and my app also approved on app store review our last version. but i would like to use it from Server or using any third party. so that i can lock my app  and special people can use it by getting code from me.
Any suggestion plz ?

I tried Test Flight and Want to use Server to download it.

Comment: Please read tag descriptors before using the tag.

Answer (score 2):

I use:

- In-House alternative [link](https://www.goodbarber.com/blog/how-to-distribute-ios-app-out-of-the-store-with-ios-enterprise-program-a871/) with just uploading the .ipa file (pros: distribution with just 2 clicks)
- [App Center](https://appcenter.ms) (pros: can create different groups of testers)

Comment: Can you do it for me ? i will pay you.

Comment: Hi, over 1 month ago I tried to create (.ipa) file and uploaded with minifest and link with a HTML page on my server. but when I tried to install it, it says not verified device or something like this alert. Is there anyone can help me for this ? Apple didn't approve Enterprise account. Is there any way to download my (.ipa) file without Enterprise account ?

Comment: Maybe you mean "Untrusted developer"? In this case go to Settings -> General -> VPN & Device Management -> Select your app -> Trust.

Comment: On VPN & Device Management I went over and over now and before but it's now showing any app list or my app there to make it Trust. Would you help please ?

Comment: @MDToufikAhamed In order to protect your app from piracy, you need to provide the ID of the device where you want to test your app from. See here: https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev31de635e5